# What is difference between running a process in test mode of Tibco Designer and in Tibco Administrator?

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I created a classic BusinessWorks process using BW 5.10 (Tibco TRA version 5.7, Tibco Designer 5.7.4.4, Tibco Administrator 5.7). The process worked fine in test node in Tibco Designer, and on the same machine I have created a BW domain and deployed the ear file in Tibco Administrator without any error. However the process can't be started with the error below with message code **BW-TIBSS-100001**:

```
Activation error with process starter [process/sendZugstandort_Hannover.process]Activation error with process starter [process/sendZugstandort_Hannover.process]
at com.tibco.pe.core.ProcessStarter.setState(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.if(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.resume(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.startNotFT(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.a(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.do(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.a(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.main(Unknown Source)caused by: Cannot activate Event Source: Specified message type does not exist..
at com.tibco.smartsockets.plugin.SSEventSource.activate(SSEventSource.java:150)
at com.tibco.pe.core.ProcessStarter.setState(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.if(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.resume(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.startNotFT(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.a(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.do(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.a(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.main(Unknown Source)
```

My question is:

- What is the essential difference between running a BW process in test mode of Designer and Tibco Administrator?
- Why does my process only in test mode of designer and not in Tibco Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve my issue by adding manually additional resources to enterprise archive. Normally all resources referenced in a process definition will be automatically added to enterprise archive, but for SmartSockets palette, SmartSockets message types definition are not included in enterprise archive.

Lesson learned: When process works fine in test mode of Designer, but not in Tibco Administrator, then check first the ear file, if all resources all included in it.